# How to correctly delete a dynamically added div panel from an array in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays

I am trying to add a delete function for my `ConnectedProducts.js` page, but can't seem to pass the correct ID to my Modal which handles the delete function. The delete function should delete a div panel (which are saved in an array) from said page, and works by clicking a button on the page which opens up a Modal asking for confirmation before deleting.

I am not exactly sure how I even get the correct ID from my array since the divs are added to the array with the `.map` function. The delete function seems to atleast somewhat work since it takes an index number and deletes the specified indexed div. (Shortened the following code to a minimal working example)

**ConnectedProducts.js:**

```js
import React from "react";
import "../Overview.css";
import Approve from "../icons/icon-dc_alert-success-filled.svg";
import Denied from "../icons/icon-dc_callout_hint.svg";
import Close from "../icons/icon-dc_close.svg";
import Add from "../icons/icon-dc_add.svg";
import ModalAddProduct from "../components/ModalAddProduct.jsx";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import ModalDelete from "../components/ModalDelete.jsx";
import ModalProductSettings from "../components/ModalProductSettings.jsx";


const ConnectedProducts = () => {
  const [stateComment, setStateComment] = React.useState("");
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [openDelete, setOpenDelete] = React.useState(false);
  const [openSettings, setOpenSettings] = React.useState(false);
  const [states, setStates] = React.useState([]);
 

  const handleComment = (e) => {
    setStateComment(e.target.value);
  };

  function getIndex() {
    // What exactly do I need to return here? If I return 1 for an example I need to add 
    // two panels, and only the second panel would get deleted while the first one stays no matter what
    // panel I want to delete
    return 1;
  }

  return (
    <div id="wrapper">
      {open && <ModalAddProduct setOpen={setOpen} setStates={setStates} />}
      {openDelete && <ModalDelete setOpen={setOpenDelete} setStates={setStates} states={states} index={getIndex()} />}
      {openSettings && <ModalProductSettings setOpen={setOpenSettings} states={states} setStates={setStates} index={getIndex()} />}
      <div class="component-headline">
        <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          [APPLICATION NAME] - Connected Products:
        </h1>
      </div>

      <div class="center-product-content">
        <div id="center_connect">


          
          //Here the divs get added to the "states" array after clicking Add on the Modal
          {states.map((state, index) => {
            
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                {state.stateSelect !== "Select Product Type" && state.stateSelect !== "" && (
                  <div class="app-box" key={index}>
                    <img
                      class="image"
                      alt="Logo"
                      src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1968353/2535/i/600/depositphotos_25357041-stock-photo-close-up-of-machine-gears.jpg"
                    />
                    <div class="box-content">
                      <h3 class="product-h3"> {state.state} </h3>
                      <textarea
                        class="product-textarea"
                        placeholder="Short description of Product; max. 280 characters"
                        readOnly={true}
                        onChange={(e) => handleComment(e)}
                        value={state.stateComment}
                      >
                        {state.stateComment}
                      </textarea>
                      <h3 class="product-h3-second"> Configuration </h3>
                      <div class="approve-img">
                        <img
                          class="product-image"
                          alt="Icon"
                          src={Approve}
                          
                        ></img>
                      </div>
                      <div
                        class="button-content new"
                        id="product-delete-button"
                      >
                        <img
                          class="close_dyn"
                          alt="Delete"
                          src={Close}
                          onClick={() => setOpenDelete(true)}
                        ></img>
                      </div>
                      <div class="module-button center_button_dyn">
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          class="btn btn-secondary"
                          onClick={() => setOpenSettings(true)}
                        ></button>
                        <div class="button-animation"></div>
                        <div class="button-content">
                          <span class="content-text">Configure</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )}


              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
        <div
          style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
          class="app-box"
          onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
        >
          <img
            class="image"
            src={Add}
            alt="Add"
            style={{ height: "150px", position: "relative", left: "550px" }}
          />
          <p
            style={{ fontSize: "larger", position: "relative", left: "600px" }}
          >
            Add Connected Product
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="module-button" style={{ left: "1340px" }}>
          <Link to="/overview">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"></button>
          </Link>
          <div class="button-animation"></div>
          <div class="button-content">
            <span class="content-text">Done</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>

  );
};

export default ConnectedProducts;
```

**ModalDelete.jsx:**

```js
import React from "react";


const ModalDelete = ({ setOpen, setOpenSettings, index, states, setStates }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    function handleEscapeKey(event) {
      if (event.code === "Escape") {
        setOpen(false);
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleEscapeKey);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleEscapeKey);
  });

  //Delete Function
  const deleteProduct = (index) => {
    
    const copy = [...states];
    copy.splice(index, 1);
    setStates(copy);

    console.log(index)
    setOpen(false);
    setOpenSettings(false);
  }

return(
 //HTML shortened up to the responsible button click for the delete function
  <button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-light btn"
  onClick={() => deleteProduct(index)}
  ></button>)

export default ModalDelete;
```

**ModalAddProduct.jsx:** (adds the panel to `ConnectedProducts.js`)

```js
import React from "react";

const ModalAddProduct = ({ setOpen, setStates }) => {
  const [ModalState, setModalState] = React.useState("");
  const [ModalStateComment, setModalStateComment] = React.useState("");
  const [ModalSelect, setModalSelect] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function handleEscapeKey(event) {
      if (event.code === "Escape") {
        setOpen(false);
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener("keydown", handleEscapeKey);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleEscapeKey);
  });

  const handleComment = (e) => {
    setModalStateComment(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setModalState(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSelect = (e) => {
    setModalSelect(e.target.value);
  }
  
//Function to add new panels
  const addNewProduct = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    setStates( oldArray => [...oldArray, {
      state: ModalState,
      stateComment: ModalStateComment,
      stateSelect: ModalSelect,
    }])
  };


...

export default ModalAddProduct;
```

What am I missing to dynamically delete any selected panel? I tried so many different approaches to this, but can't seem to find a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
import uuid from "uuid/v4";         
const addNewProduct = () => {
  setOpen(false);
  setStates( oldArray => [...oldArray, {
    state: ModalState,
    stateComment: ModalStateComment,
    stateSelect: ModalSelect,
    id:uuid()
  }])
};

//this will add id to each added item
```

```
const deleteProduct = (id) => {
    "Set Your state"((prevItem) => {
      return prevItem.filter((item) => item.id != id);
    });
  };

//In delete, function it filters the state and check whether the id is there or not 
//let me know if it works
```

Comment: Do you mean with "Set Your State" setStates which is given to the DeleteModal from ConnectedProducts ?